# h2o: iterate through rows

Tags: python, h2o

I know h2o's internal data model is column oriented (namely an H2OFrame is a collection of H2OVec). However, the library I'd like to use requires to iterate through the rows of an H2OFrame.

Is there a clean way to get an iterator on the rows or do I need to resort to indexing like

```
iris = h2o.import_file(path=".../iris_wheader.csv")
for i in xrange(iris.nrow):
    foo( iris[i,:].as_data_frame(use_pandas=False)[1] )
```

I know it's going to be slow, I'm using `h2o.h2o.export_file` when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a row-wise apply.
    `iris.apply(foo,1)`

Where `foo` is some lambda that h2o understands (there are some limits on what can go in there, but all basic math ops should work fine).

Cliff

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Cliff said (which is the faster way), you can also pull the entire data frame into the Python space and then iterate on it.

```
pd_frame = h2o_frame.as_data_frame(use_pandas=True)
```

If you don't want Pandas in the end:

```
np_array = h2o_frame.as_data_frame(use_pandas=True).as_matrix()
```

A little more about your library might help answer the question better.