# Python h2o frame to np array reshape

Tags: python, h2o

I'm a newbie in python.

I have an h2o frame table having `1000` rows and `25` columns, I would like to convert this table to numpy array and reshape to (5,5)

I used this code:

```
mynarray=np.array([np.array(nrows).astype(np.float32).reshape(5,5) for nrows in myh2oframe])
```

Error I received is cannot copy sequence with size 1604 to array axis with dimension 1

Comment: `...for nrows in myh2oframe` are you sure this is iterating through the rows of the `h2o.Frame`? Maybe consider [converting it to an `np.array` first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34346322/1011724) and then reshape it one go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start with a small clarification. You can't reshape a `1000 x 25` array into a `5 x 5` array. The number of elements in the original and reshaped arrays has to be the same.

From your code, looks like you are trying to reshape each row of h2o frame, with `1 x 25`, dimension into `5 x 5` numpy array, which should results in a `1000 x 5 x 5` array, since there are 1000 rows. Here is an example to do that and you can modify/apply it to your specific case.

```
import h2o
import numpy as np

# initialize h2o
h2o.init()

# create a (1000, 25) h2o frame with real values (no missing values)
hf = h2o.create_frame(rows=1000, cols=25, real_fraction=1, missing_fraction=0) 

# First convert to a pandas df, then to a numpy array
num_array = hf.as_data_frame().as_matrix()

# Reshape the array
reshaped_array = num_array.reshape(1000, 25, 25)

# Check the dimensions of the reshaped array
reshaped_array.shape
# The output should be: (1000, 5, 5)
```

Hope this helps with your problem.